# Converting a .pickle model to a tar.gz model for use in Sagemaker

Tags: scikit-learn, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker, tar.gz

How would I convert a model saved as a .pickle file to tar.gz format?

This is an XGBoost model that has been trained using Scikit-learn and Cross Validation. The tar.gz format is required for deployment in Amazon Sagemaker.

Answer (score 1):

You can just compress the pickle file by running - `tar -czvf model.tar.gz model.pickle`. Upload it to S3 and use it in SageMaker to deploy your model.

I work at AWS and my opinions are my own.